# Organizing variables on mailto form submit

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using mailto on a form to open the default email service and create an email. However, all the fields on the form look horrible when they appear on the email. I have three fields noun1, verb, noun2 and when they're submitted, on the body of the email it shows up as, for example

```
noun1= I
verb= ate
noun2= food
```

Is there some way to specify how to organize/display these variables on the email body when submit is clicked so that it is formatted  on the email body as

```
I ate food
```

?

The form, by request:

```
<form id= "formx" method="post" action="mailto:email@email.com" enctype="text/plain">

<p><label for="id_noun1">noun1:</label>
    <input id="id_noun1" type="text" name="noun1"/></p>
<p><label for="id_verb">Verb:</label>
    <input id="id_verb" type="text" name="verb" /></p>
<p><label for="id_noun2">noun2:</label>
    <input id="id_noun2" type="text" name="noun2"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: I specified that horrible means the email's body contains A= 1, B= 2, C= 3. I cleaned up the language of the question so that it's clearer.

Comment: Does not seem horrible to me. What's _not_ horrible in this case?

Comment: Show us the code you are using, that might help us figure out, what you are trying to

Comment: "I'm using mailto on a form to open the default email service and create an email." — Don't, [it doesn't work](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks for the help everybody, I guess.

What I settled on was taking the input from the form, creating a new element via javascript, making a link and adjusting the href on the fly. Finally, I have a javascript click event that opens an email with the information formatted as I want.

```
var a= document.getElementById('a');
var b= document.getElementById('b');
var c= document.getElementById('c');
var link = document.createElement('a');

link.setAttribute('href', 'mailto:me.com' 
+ '?subject= Subject' + '&body='+ 'I am a ' + a.value + ', I like to ' + b.value 
+ ', I also like doing ' + c.value  
);
link.click();
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all i have to say email by just html or javascript will end up looking weird just use php instead it is also quiet easy:

```
/first make the variables of all the things you need
        $naam = $_POST['vnaam'];
        $mail = $_POST['email'];
        $achternaam = $_POST['anaam'];
        $tel = $_POST['telefoon'];
        $message = $_POST['commentaar'];

        $Name = $naam; //senders name 
        $email = $mail; //senders e-mail adress 
        $recipient = "receivers email"; //recipient 
        $mail_body =  //add the variables and text here by using . u get the same as + in javascript ;
        //mail body 
        $subject = "Contact formulier van: " . $naam . " " . $achternaam; //subject 
        $header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; //optional headerfields 
if ($_POST) {
 mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header); //mail command
 exit;
        }
```

now the if statement is the most important part. it is the part where the mail function is requested from. the pros of php is that the receiver doesnt get an email with something like:
idname=Dave
or idcheckbox=true or false (weither or not he box is checked)

Comment: The OP did not mention any web server technology. Especially no mention of PHP.